# Do Boltzmann brain thought experiments suggest literally anything can form randomly?

Tags: statistical-mechanics, cosmology, entropy

Do [Boltzmann brain](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boltzmann_brain) thought experiments suggest literally anything can form randomly?

What are the limitations to what random fluctuations can form? Literally any physical, material object?

Lastly, I am curious as to how this compares to an object with a high degree of complexity always existing. For example, is a bike more likely to always exist for no reason than it being created by random fluctuations? Or is it less likely?

Comment: You have to consider the question of whether a bike can be said to exist in any meaningful sense if there is no one to perceive it. It’s the same as the famous question about whether a tree falling in the forest makes a noise if there’s no one to hear it.

Comment: The only *effective* limitation is the available space / time, but essentially the probability of any arbitrary object spontaneously forming is non-zero. Saying that a certain state is impossible is an approximation of saying that the expected incidence rate is longer than the current age of the Universe

Comment: Was this question inspired by this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4Stzj2_Rlo4 ? :)

Comment: @MikeScott "Dear Sir, your astonishment's odd. I am always about in the quad. And that's why this tree, continues to be, as observed by, yours faithfully, God."

Comment: Noting that (1) 'reductio ad absurdum' is inseperable from BB's (2) Ha ha. Ha ha ha. Ha ha ha ha ha . || [Such comments seem to spontaneously de-exist with higher probability than I'd expect in this universe. I submit that it's as serious as any other one in this subject area and as worthy as any of retention. || Bzzzzt ... .

Answer (score 18):

A very handy way of looking at the statistical mechanism of a system is by looking at its so-called [phase space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phase_space) (read as state space).

Consider a [microstate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microstate_(statistical_mechanics)#:%7E:text=Treatments%20on%20statistical%20mechanics%20define,a%20particular%20macrostate%20of%20it.) $X = (q_1, . . . , q_N, p_1, . . . , p_N)$ of a classical system that consists of a $N$ particles. Here, $q, p$ represents the position and momentum degree of freedom of the particles. Naturally, the dimension of this phase space is $2N$.

It is assumed that every microstate (a point in this phase space) is equally likely to be attained by a physical system. Each such specification of $X$ determines a [macrostate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microstate_(statistical_mechanics)#:%7E:text=Treatments%20on%20statistical%20mechanics%20define,a%20particular%20macrostate%20of%20it.). Now, if we wait for a long period of time, then every microstate would occur at least once. Such systems are called [ergodic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ergodicity).

**So yes, these $N$ particles can assume any microstate, which includes a brain popping out of nowhere** (although with a vanishing probability). However, there are more microstates corresponding to certain macrostates than others. Since each microstate is equally likely, therefore the physical system of $N$ particles is more likely to be found in certain macrostates than others. These more likely macrostates **are** the states which maximise entropy solely because they contain more microstates and hence occupy a larger volume of the phase space.

**But**...

Above, I assumed that all the $N$ particles were free to move around (i.e., there were no constraints on their dynamics). Imposing constraints (depending on the details of the dynamics, e.g., due to internal forces or conservation of total energy which then sets an upper limit on the $p$'s) reduces the volume of the phase space and, therefore, makes certain regions of the original phase space inaccessible. As a result, only those states could be reached that satisfy the imposed constraints. **As such, not every thing can form randomly**.

For more, I redirect you to this nice [article](https://arxiv.org/pdf/cond-mat/0105242.pdf).

Comment: That seems a bit vacuous. "If there's something making some microstates impossible, then those microstates would be impossible."

Comment: @Acccumulation: Maybe so, but there are real forces that might serve to prevent some microstates from being accessible. For example, it seems impossible to create free quarks by pulling bound quarks apart, because of the behavior of the strong force. It's worth emphasizing that "every microstate happens eventually" may *only* follow from "every microstate is accessible." Assuming there is no proton decay, you will never see the individual quarks in a proton evolve to become very far apart from one another.

Answer (score 3):

Anything that doesn't violate the laws of physics/logic can form. And even for things that violate the laws of physics and/or logic, the *memory* of having perceived them may still be able to form. So pretty much any *phenomenon* can form (that is, any phenomenological experience). For instance, the laws of physics say that a region of space with mass but no spacetime curvature is impossible, but it's still possible to have experiences such that it appears that there is mass but not curvature.

As to your question about a bike, the number of microstates in which a bike exists for a short time is larger than the number of microstates in which a bike exists for a very long time, so the former is more likely. On a short enough time span, though, it would be more likely to exist for a longer period of time. For instance, the probability of a bike existing for a microsecond would be larger than the probability of it existing for only a nanosecond. Most of the probability space "near" a state of bike existing also consists of a bike existing. An analogy would be drawing a circle on the ground and putting a feather inside the circle. On the scale of microseconds, the most likely state is that the feather is still inside the circle. On the scale of a year, it's very unlikely that the feather is still inside.

Comment: What if the “long time” is eternal?